# Access social readers' posts in a facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can a facebook app, have access to a social reader's post in the feed? For example, I want to have access to Washington Post's social reader post (when someone else reads an article there and it gets shown up in my news feed) from an app that I am writing. Is it possible to do so,  using FQL?

Answer (score 0):

It's easily available in the Graph API (i'll check if it's in FQL)

Basically, either way you'll need to request the `user_actions.reads` permission from your users.  (NB: not `user_actions:reads` which would be for an app whose namespace is 'reads', for news, music and video apps using the build-in actions there's a special scope)

Then, for the Graph API, just make a call to `/USER_ID/news.reads` - the response includes the recently read articles from all apps using the built-in 'read' action, example response for my account below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "REMOVED_ID", 
      "from": {
        "id": "REMOVED_MY_USER_ID", 
        "name": "REMOVED_MY_NAME"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2012-05-10T00:05:10+0000", 
      "end_time": "2012-05-10T00:05:10+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2012-05-10T00:05:10+0000", 
      "application": {
        "id": "235586169789578", 
        "name": "The Independent"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "article": {
          "id": "10150697347986736", 
          "url": "http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/the-10-best-scotch-whiskies-1488408.html", 
          "type": "article", 
          "title": "The 10 Best Scotch Whiskies"
        }
      }, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0
      }
    }, 
.... //more articles
```

Comment: how do I request the user_actions.reads permissions? I dont see this option in the request Accesss Token dialog box.  I ran the command you suggested in the post and I got the following output,  {
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/news.reads?format=json&offset=25&limit=25"
  }
}

Comment: When I clicked on the link generated by the above response, I get an auth error                                                            {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

Comment: If you're using the graph explorer, only the basic permissions are there for selection, you need to manually craft the oauth dialog to add user_actions.[something] or user_actions:[something]
The 'next' link in the graph explorer doesn't copy the token to the new window either

Comment: Aaah! Thanks for your input. I really appreciate it. Is there a place where we can find this user_action.xxx documented?

Comment: I mean to say ... list of all such actions and their meaning.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms - for arbitrary apps you'll need to know the app namespace (apps.facebook.com/SOMETHING) and the action names (no API for this, you'll have to determine it by using the app in most cases)

Comment: Igy, I am still struggling with this. This is what I have done. I went to "edit settings" and clicked on the "Auth Dialog". In user and friend permissions, I have added user_actions.news and saved changes. Now I go back to the tool - Graph API Explorer" and select my app from the drop down menu. When I give the command , GET https://graph.facebook.com/<userid>/news.read, I still get the following msg - paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/<user-id>/news.reads?format=json&offset=25&limit=25". I was expecting a list of news I have read using my social readers. Please help.